# MariaDB: <SHOW GRANTS FOR USER> does not show table level privileges?

Tags: mariadb

I am coming over to MariaDB from MySQL, I created table level grants, but when I do  it only gives:

GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO user@% IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'xxxx'

I did the grants as follows:
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON database.table  TO USER

Does MariaDB not show table level grants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get *table*-level privileges, you need a different syntax.  For example:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON dbname.tablename TO user@localhost;
```

The following gives you *database*-level privs:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON dbname.* TO user@localhost;
```

(If your table is named `.`, that will be a nightmare.)

Comment: Thank you Rick, sorry, was just a typo, I indeed did the sql statement with dbname.tablename. But somehow I am only able to do grants at full database, level, not at table, level, with MariaDB running in Docker, on a Pi. MariaDB v10.1.26. Playing around some more. -- and fixed my question --